# How to access other viewcontrollers variables/properties in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2

I know similiar questions have been asked before, but please bear with me as I am totally new at Objective C (have good knowledge on C).

My case is that I have a tab bar controller with two windows. When I press a button in "second" I change a variable `changeName`. I want to use the value of `changeName` in my "first" view controller but stumbled on to some problems:

To reach the other viewcontroller I found this from SO (unfortunately I forgot where):

```
-(NSString *)newName{

// Create a UIStoryboard object of "MainStoryBoard_iPhone" named storyboard
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:(NSString *)@"MainStoryBoard_iPhone" bundle:(NSBundle *)nil];

// Create a UIViewController object of the wanted element from MainStoryBoard_iPhone
UIViewController *secondview = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)@"secondBoard"];

return secondview.changeName;
}
```

Which I have in my first.m. `MainStoryBoard_iPhone` is the name of the .xib/storyboard-file.

but no. Error says

```
Property 'changeName' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'
```

In my second.h I have

```
 @property (readwrite, retain) NSString *changeName;
```

and in second.m

```
 @synthesize changeName;
```

All help is appreciated, but please keep in mind that I have only used OOP for two days. 
Thank you all in advance

EDIT: And what input should I have here?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
mylabel.text = Name; // or [mylabel.text Name] or something? 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the view controller returned to your customized second view controller (as `UIViewController` does not have the property `changeName`).

So do the following :

```
// Create a UIViewController object of the wanted element from MainStoryBoard_iPhone
SecondViewController *secondview = (SecondViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)@"secondBoard"];
```

I assume SecondViewController is the name of your second controller.

Comment: Thats what I wanted, but I see that I do not have to cast it if I use `SecondViewController *secondview` instead of `UIViewController * secondview`. But could you then explain to me what I have to insert in `-(void)viewDidLoad` to change my label? Functions/methods in OOP really confuses me.

Comment: [myLabel setText:@"My Text"] should do the trick. Make sure myLabel is not nil (as this will still work with no errors but nothing will be actually set)

Comment: Thank you, but that will not set myLabel to the returned text from method `Name`, would it? And how do I assure that myLabel is not nil?

Comment: I tried `[mylabel setText:[self Name]];`, no errors but still no action on my label :\ Doing it your way did produce text, so it should work, shouldn`t it?

Comment: I see that my problem is that I have the tabbarcontroller in the middle which also has to get a pointer `*tabBar`, but UITabBarController class dont have `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` so I don`t know how to succeed at this

Comment: debug your code or NSLog your mylabel object. If the label is an outlet make sure it is connected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to pass a string from FirstViewController to set a text field in SecondViewController, so:

1- In SecondViewController.h

> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *someTextField;// this is linked to a UITextField

2- In FirstViewController.m:

> #import "SecondViewController.h"

3- I will do this after a press of a button in the FirstViewController:

> SecondViewController *SecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] 
>   initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
>
> //set fields values
>
> ```
>     SecondView.someTextField.text = @"HeLLO from First";
>
>
> UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: SecondView];
> ```
>
> //show AdView
>
> ```
>    [self.navigationController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
> ```

4- This is it!

5- There is a case, if I'm in FirstViewController and wanted to set a string property in the SecondViewController with the same way, the string won't get the value till you press a some kinda button in SecondViewController, it won't get it like in viewDidLoad for example! don't know why.